# Why does vertical-align not work in this case?

Tags: html, css

I used to align text inside DIVs with CSS and `vertical-align`. I'm now trying, but I can't get it to work.

My task is to simply `vertical-align: center;` the white text inside the pink DIV. But whatever I do, the text remains starting in the upper left corner.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center; background-color:#FF0000">
  <div style="width: 587px; height: 180px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; background-color:#00FF00">
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;"> </div>
    <!--<br>-->
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 530px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FF00FF">
      <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: text-bottom;"> <b>Center me vertically, please!</b> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also [fiddle around](http://jsfiddle.net/) with it.

I tried different solutions as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div) [on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertically-center-in-div-with-css) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) site, but I can't get them to work. **So why won't a browser vertically align my text in a nice pink DIV?**

Comment: set the other div's height from 20px to 180px and try again

Comment: Are you sure you need `vertical-align` here? The element has a fixed height which allows to center it vertically in another way.

Comment: Here's an article that can help you understand why: http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's the "proper" CSS way to do it, but if you set the `line-height` of your pink div to the same height (30px) then it will center vertically:

```
<div style="width:100%; text-align:center; background-color:#FF0000">
<div style="width: 587px; height: 180px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; background-color:#00FF00">
    <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;">
    </div>
    <!--<br>-->
    <div style="height: 30px; line-height: 30px; width: 530px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FF00FF">
        <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: text-bottom;">
            <b>Center me vertically, please!</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, thanks for that! But I wan't to understand why this is needed, as I remember that I didn't need that before - for example for elements. Is there an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: table` to the wrapping div and set `vertical-align: middle`.

```
  <div style="width:100%; text-align:center; background-color:#FF0000">
      <div style="width: 587px; height: 180px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; text-align:center; background-color:#00FF00">
        <div style="height: 20px; width: 1px;"> </div>
        <!--<br>-->
        <div style="height: 30px; width: 530px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 16px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#FF00FF; display: table;">
          <div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"> <b>Center me vertically, please!</b> </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gaecshs7/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works. But I find Dismissile's answer a little bit prettier, as the DIV container remains a DIV. Still the question is open for WHY a single vertical-align doesn't work her. :)

Comment: "Applies to inline-level and table-cell elements" ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

It does not align to block elements.

Comment: You can use Dismissile's answer for sure, but you need to know the specific height. This works with dynamic height.